# Django FullCalendar with Django 2.x or 3.x

Tags: javascript, python, django, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Okay, I know that this question has been asked a lot of times, but it seems that I can't understand it by myself. I need to implement FullCalendar into my Django application, and after I downloaded FullCalendar with all the statics and stuff, and after rendered it on my page, I just can't add new Events by any chance.

I have my Event model, with start_date, end_date, id, and title, like someone explained it here. After that, I made a function in my views.py called all_events, where event = Event.object.all(), and put that in the context variable. I have no forms at this time, I just want to render it after I enter the data from my admin page - for now. Want to be as simple as possible. This is my code :

```
models.py

class Events(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
views.py

def events(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    context = {
        "events": all_events,
    }
    return render(request, '.../selectable.html', context)
```

```
urls.py

    path('.../add_event', add_event, name='add_event'),
```

And my html page :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content_row %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/core/main.css' %}' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/daygrid/main.css' %}' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.css' %}' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/list/main.css' %}' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    height: 'auto',
                    locale: 'sr',
                    plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                    },
                    defaultDate: '2019-12-13',
                    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: [
                        {% for e in eventlist %}
                            {
                                title: '{{ e.event_name }}',
                                start: '{{ e.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                                end: '{{ e.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                            },
                        {% endfor %}
                    ]
                });

                calendar.render();
            });

        </script>
        <style>

            body {
                margin: 40px 10px;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            #calendar {
                max-width: 900px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <script src='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js' %}'></script>
    <script src='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/interaction/main.js' %}'></script>
    <script src='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/daygrid/main.js' %}'></script>
    <script src='{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.js' %}'></script>
    <script src="{% static 'fullcalendar/packages/core/locales/sr.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my page source, it seems that i have events from my database, but without the data.

```
<script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    height: 'auto',
                    locale: 'sr',
                    plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                    },
                    defaultDate: '2019-12-13',
                    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: [

                            {
                                title: '',
                                start: '',
                                end: '',
                            },

                            {
                                title: '',
                                start: '',
                                end: '',
                            },

                            {
                                title: '',
                                start: '',
                                end: '',
                            },

                    ]
                });

                calendar.render();
            });

        </script>
```

I don't need anything fancy and stuff, I just want to figure how it works. 
I didn't installed Django-scheduler, or Django-fullcalendar, because I don't know if that's required?!
So, once again, I got calendar rendered properly on my page, and static's also, I just can't add or see any events from my model. 
Hope to get my answer. Thanks.

Comment: any errors in the browser console? Can you show us what the `events: [
                        {% for e in events%}
                            {
                                title: '{{ e.name }}',
                                start: '{{ e.start|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                                end: '{{ e.end|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                            },
                        {% endfor %}
                    ]` code actually renders (use your page's View Source feature to show it)?

Comment: P.S. Also, judging by your code, you haven't included all the necessary fullCalendar plugins. Each view type (e.g. daygrid, timegrid, list etc) and other features requires a separate plugin file (both JS and CSS in most cases - you've included the core JS file, but not plugin files, and no CSS files at all as far as I can see). See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index for more info.

Comment: I have all the other statics in my base.html, forgot to mention that, sorry. @ADyson

Comment: When i inspect the page, i have this : 
The script from “http://localhost:8000/main/calendar/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8000/main/calendar/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js”.

TypeError: t is null

Plugin file not loaded for list

Comment: Most of that is irrelevant to fullCalendar I think (unless it prevents any of the code from executing). The very last bit might be though - it looks like you missed out the "list" plugin file from fullCalendar.

Comment: @ADyson, yeah i know, most of that doesnt have anything to FullC.. 
Any idea how to implement it properly? :)

Comment: Well I don't know about the first errors particularly, but a MIME type error is usually a misconfiguration in your server. For the "list" error you need to make sure you have correctly included the JS file for the fullCalendar "list" plugin in your page.

Comment: @ADyson, yeah, but i think that a fullcalendar itself is not configured right. Something about the models, or something in the views.. Did you worked with it before?

Comment: Yeah lots (check my answer history under the fullCalendar tag!), but let's fix one error at a time. Fix the list error, see if it helps. Then move onto the next thing. P.S. You'll notice that in my first comment I also asked you from some other info. If you could update your question with that info, it would help a lot. If you aren't seeing events, it's often because the event data is invalid in some way. Fullcalendar does not always throw errors when this happens, unfortunately, it often simply ignores the invalid event.

Comment: @ADyson
I added all the links and scripts for the rest of the statics, which are included in my base.html, is that it? Did you worked with FullC and Django together? ^^

Comment: No. But I worked with it alongside other server-side frameworks. I get the general idea. I can see in your base.html you forgot `fullcalendar/packages/list/main.js` which is the cause of that plugin error. Did you not fix that yet? It's the 3rd time I've mentioned it.

Comment: And you seem to be including `fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js` twice for no reason - once in base and once in your page. That could cause weird issues potentially. At the least it's pointless to load the same file twice. Just remove it from the HTML, if everything else is being declared in base.

Comment: Why do you want fullCalendar in your base template though? Are you putting a calendar on every page of the site? If not, it's a lot of stuff to load for no reason. And you probably ought to load the .min.js and .min.css versions of each of those files instead, because they're smaller (being minified) and you don't need to debug them, so it doesn't matter if the code is obfuscated.

Comment: And I'll ask you again to provide the rendered event data, please, since you still haven't done that either. It's useful. Do you understand what i'm asking you to do?

Comment: @ADyson
Hmmm, it seems like there is nothing between the square brackets in the page source.. events: []

Comment: I cleaned the double scripts and links, and removed them from the base. They are only in the calendar(selectable.html) page.

Comment: I would guess your django `eventlist` variable is empty, then. I'm afraid that one's down to you, I don't know enough python / django to help you with that, unless someone else pops up on this question. I only note that your "views.py" doesn't appear to refer to anything called eventlist, so maybe that's a clue.

Comment: @ADyson
After some cleaning, in my page source, i get events: [{title: "", start:"",end:""},{title: "", start:"",end:""},{title: "", start:"",end:""}]
So i got 3 events, with no title and other data.. I have 3 events in my database.

Comment: I edited my question, so you can see at the top whole page source.

Comment: Next step is to figure out why those properties aren't populated, then , I guess. Again. I'm not sure where to help

Comment: @ADyson
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Still can't figure why are those not rendering properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it right, after some time. 
I'll post my code here.

```
Those are Events in fullcalendar.html, with time hours.

events: [
          {% for i in events %}
             {
                  title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                  start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i"}}',
                  end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',
              },
          {% endfor %}
        ]
```

```
My event function inside views.py

def event(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    get_event_types = Events.objects.only('event_type')

    if request.GET:
        event_arr = []
        if request.GET.get('event_type') == "all":
            all_events = Events.objects.all()
        else:
            all_events = Events.objects.filter(event_type__icontains=request.GET.get('event_type'))

        for i in all_events:
            event_sub_arr = {}
            event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event_name
            start_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.start_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            end_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.end_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
            event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
            event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))

    context = {
        "events": all_events,
        "get_event_types": get_event_types,

    }
    return render(request, 'app/yourFullcalendarPage.html', context)
```

```
Event urls.py

path('calendar/', event, name='calendar'),
```

```
And finaly, Events model.py

class Events(models.Model):
    event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.event_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'
```